# Insert New Item's On RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a REST Service that paginate my requests... I need to insert on my recyclerview 20 itens and keep the 20 itens before loaded.

This is my request...

```
VeiculoRequestHelper.veiculosPaginatedRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<VeiculoPaginated>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(VeiculoPaginated response) {
            AnalyticsTracker.getInstance().sendEvent(AnalyticsEnum.Category.MY_VEHICLE, AnalyticsEnum.Action.CLICK, AnalyticsEnum.Label.SUCCESS);

            isLast = response.isLast();

            ArrayList<Veiculo> veiculoArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            veiculoArrayList.addAll(response.getContent());

            veiculos = veiculoArrayList;

            mAdapter.addItem(veiculos);

            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            AnalyticsTracker.getInstance().sendEvent(AnalyticsEnum.Category.MY_VEHICLE, AnalyticsEnum.Action.CLICK, AnalyticsEnum.Label.ERROR);

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Erro ao realizar listagem de veículos.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

This is my adapter method to add new itens...

```
    public void addItem(ArrayList<Veiculo> veiculosArray) {
    if (veiculos != null) {
        veiculos.clear();
        veiculos.addAll(veiculosArray);
        notifyItemInserted(veiculos.size() - 1);
    } else {
        veiculos = veiculosArray;
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

What i'm doing wrong? The itens is inserted but not keeping the old itens... Help please!

Answer (score 1):

The old data will be cleared in `addItem(ArrayList<Veiculo> veiculosArray)`:

```
if (veiculos != null) {
  veiculos.clear(); // here they will be cleared
  veiculos.addAll(veiculosArray);
  notifyItemInserted(veiculos.size() - 1);
}
```

Remove this line to keep the old items.

Comment: When i remove veiculos.clear(); it insert all the data, but the recyclerview go to begin, not keep on the last item...

Answer (score 0):

in your onResponse:

```
 ArrayList<Veiculo> veiculoArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            veiculoArrayList.addAll(response.getContent());

            veiculos = veiculoArrayList;

            mAdapter.addItem(veiculos);

            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

see what is happening, `veiculoArrayList` is being assigned to `veiculos` means new 20 items are now in it. 
passing veiculos into `mAdapter.addItem(veiculos);`
and in your `addItem` method

```
veiculos.clear();
veiculos.addAll(veiculosArray);
```

means what ever was in `veiculos` will clear and new list `veiculosArray` would be added in it (means new 20 items). You just don't need to clear, add new items list and `notifyDatasetChanged()`. 
to keep focus on last item, you just need to set recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);
and obviously position would be veiculos.size() before adding new items into it.

```
notifyItemRangeInserted(lastListSize, newList.size());
```

Comment: When i remove veiculos.clear(); it insert all the data, but the recyclerview go to begin, not keep on the last item...

Comment: i updated my answer, you cam move position to last item.

Comment: @FelipeA. `notifyItemRangeInserted(lastListSize, newList.size());` see this in answer.

Comment: Didnt work too, still updating data and moving to top